# How to suppress endless log print for mesos master?

Tags: mesos

After start mesos master, within every few seconds, it will print

***Current disk usage 12.64%. Max allowed age...***

it seems to be endless, how can I suppress the print?

My start command is:

***mesos-master --ip=10.195.252.12 --work_dir=/tmp/mesos***

Comment: Try to chagne logging level http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/logging/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a couple of things. Enable `quie`t logging so that you don't log to stderr:

```
mesos-master --ip=10.195.252.12 --work_dir=/tmp/mesos --quiet
```

you can also adjust your log level in general by using the `--logging_level` option

```
mesos-master --ip=10.195.252.12 --work_dir=/tmp/mesos --logging_level=ERROR
```

The above will only log errors which is much less verbose than the default `INFO`

Hope it helps.